# React , JSX props parser

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

What is the difference between usage of

```
<Component key={1} /> (1)
```

and

```
<Component key=1 />   (2)
```

what is the wrong way to pass number prop here ?

is parser make some logic there before to pass it to the component in the first point ?

Comment: In the second example, it would be interpreted as a string (if that's even valid JSX).

Comment: I want to understand is any difference between compiler work if I pass <Component someProp="123" /> and <Component someProp={123} />

Comment: Those are two different values. One is a number and the other is a string.

Comment: of course @kelly , is compiler doing some work if I wrote key={1} ? is compiler doing some small work if I wrote key='1' , I want to understand what is the best way to pass it as a props that the parser compile it more easy

Comment: That is entirely dependent on the parser. The difference is so miniscule that it is negligible anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer: The Correct Way to Pass Props/Keys

if you are passing a string you can pass it as:

`<Component someProp="123" />`

In this case, the prop you are using is `key` which is expecting a string,
You should either pass it as:

`<Component someProp="123" />`

or if it is a variable:

```js
const someKey = 1;

const component = (<Component someProp={someProp.toString()} />)
```

### What happens when the app is built

> is parser make some logic there before to pass it to the component in the first point ?

`key=1` would give you errors like
`JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text.` and not render properly if at all.

#### keys will always be converted to strings

Keys are expect to be strings or a type that can be converted to a string. Looking at the react code you will see that there is a function  [testStringCoercion](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/shared/CheckStringCoercion.js#L45) that will check if the value is a string or can be converted to a string.

### Summary

You should pass your keys as a string. If you to not pass it as a string, it will still convert it to a string if possible or it will throw an error.

more on using keys: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component

more on using props: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I want to understand is any difference between compiler work if I pass <Component someProp="123" /> and <Component someProp={123} />

Comment: updated my answer, in short. keys will be converted to string if possible

Comment: is compiler doing some work if I wrote key={1} ? is compiler doing some small work if I wrote key='1' , I want to understand what is the best way to pass it as a props that the parser compile it more easy , I didn't see answer of my question

Comment: The answer to your question is that compiler will do the same amount of work regardless. The best way to pass it is to pass it as a string but it will not affect compile time or run time. If you read the `testStringCoercion` code that i have linked, you can see that it will covert it to a string anyway by running
`'' + whatEverKeyYouPassed`
If you are looking for ways to boost your build time or run time, this is not going to make a difference.